# Instagram blocks me for the requests with 429

Tags: python-requests, instagram, http-status-code-429

I have used a lot of requests to `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` to check if a pseudo was existing and now I am getting 429.

Before, I had just to wait few minutes to make the 429 disapear. Now it is persistent ! :( I'm trying once a day, it doesnt work anymore.

Do you know anything about instagram requests limitation ?

Do you have any workaround please ? Thanks

Code ...

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/test123/?__a=1')
res = str(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header, otherwise, the website thinks that your a bot, and will block you.

```
import requests

URL = "https://www.instagram.com/bla/?__a=1"
HEADERS = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

print(response.status_code) # <- Output: 200
```

Comment: My IP is already compromised. The issue is not that the requests seem to be made by a bot, the issue is that I need to make a lot of requests (200 per hour). Instagram might count requests regarding the client IP.

Comment: Your solution works... How is it possible ? I don't understand why my code was working for weeks !!