# How to scrape star ratings using Selenium or Beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the ratings based on stars. The stars are in different colors and can be distinguished in Chrome. However, the stars are all the same in the tags. Is there a way to scrape the rating for each sub-category based on the color of the stars, e.g., Work/Life Balance should have a rating of 3.

The webpage can be found here: https://www.glassdoor.ca/Reviews/Employee-Review-AAR-RVW40036525.htm

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had a look at the webpage source, and it looks like it's using JavaScript to change the colour of the span elements, meaning it's gonna be very hard to scrape using selenium.

Comment: Thank you. The answer might be in the class name.

Comment: Do you only want the ratings under the 3-star dropdown? Or also all other dropdowns?

Comment: All others. They can be done the same way. It seems that each class name of the div tag for the stars corresponds to a value from 1 to 5.

Comment: you can use element.get_attribute('class')  (The class probably sets a clipping region...)

Comment: @VictorWang If you have a _full_ solution based on my answer, please share it as an answer too.

Comment: Yes, I will. Still testing the code.

Comment: @VictorWang I suggest that you un-accept my answer, not to discourage others from providing a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate between the ratings, the class names are different for each category of rating. Here is an example of all the class names based on rating, the value is the class name. This can start you off with what you need

```
{
"one_star" : "css-152xdkl",
"two_star" : "css-19o85uz",
"three_star" : "css-1ihykkv",
"four_star" : "css-1c07csa",
"five_star" : "css-1dc0bv4",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I used mostly BeautifulSoup because I'm more comfortable with it.

```
# Find all the reviews on the page
reviews = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gdReview')

# I used BeautifulSoup to collect the ratings
for review in reviews:
    # Convert the Selenium element for a review into a BeautifulSoup object
    review_source = review.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(review_source, 'lxml')

    # Find the sub-ratings tag
    sub_ratings_tag = soup.find("div", {"class": "tooltipContainer"})
    # Find all the "li" tags
    li_tags = sub_ratings_tag.find_all("li")

    # Loop over each "li" tag and collect the ratings
    star_dict = {"css-152xdkl": 1, "css-19o85uz": 2, "css-1ihykkv": 3,
                 "css-1c07csa": 4, "css-1dc0bv4": 5}
    sub_rating_dict = {}
    for li_tag in li_tags:
        div_tags = li_tag.find_all("div")
        for div_tag in div_tags:                
            # Get the classname and the rating name
            if div_tag.has_attr("class"):
                div_class=div_tag["class"][0]
            else:
                sub_cat = div_tag.text.strip()
        star_value = star_dict[div_class]
        sub_rating_dict[sub_cat] = star_value
```

Comment: There's no need to use Selenium, just add the `user-agent` header. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65313688/12349734)