# Web-Scraping: no more result after few successful tries - Bs4 + Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape rates of this website: https://www.ville-ideale.fr/avon_77014

[image]

I used Jupyter and now Google Colab = same issue after a few reloads of my script. I don't understand why?

For the global rate, I used BS4 :

```
url = 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/avon_77014'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

# Note générale
ng = soup.find(id="ng")
print(ng.text)
```

Earlier I got this output:

```
5,67 / 10
```

Now, without touching anything, I have this error:

```
AttributeError
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-68-72ae43ee2385> in <module>()
              9 # Note générale
             10 ng = soup.find(id="ng")
        ---> 11 print(ng.text)
        
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

And for the table, I used df :

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
dfs[0]
```

The same issue after a few reloads of my script.

Before:

```
                       0    1
    0      Environnement  675
    1         Transports  638
    2           Sécurité  438
    3              Santé  431
    4  Sports et loisirs  694
    5            Culture  594
    6       Enseignement  644
    7          Commerces  500
    8     Qualité de vie  556
```

After:

```
Error
    XMLSyntaxError
      File "<string>", line unknown
    XMLSyntaxError: no text parsed from document
```

I think that the website blocks requests after a few times. I need to do it for ~100 URLs so I don't know what to do rn...

I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: *I think that the website blocks requests after a few times* -- You are probably correct.  You will have to wait until they unblock you and try again.

Comment: See if adding a `user-agent` header helps. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65313688/12349734)

Comment: Hello, user-agent didn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

You should add some error handling, checking the request and the element you tried to select.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

SITE = 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/avon_77014'

def main():
  response = requests.get(SITE)

  # Print an error message if it wasn't successful
  if response.status_code == 200:
    # parse the html and select the data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    
    # I recommed using select and select_one to select your elements, since they use css selectors.
    ng = soup.select_one("#ng")
    if ng:
      print(ng.text)
    else:
      print("Selected element doesn't exist")
  else:
    print("Request to", site, "failed with error", resoonse.reason)

# makes sure it only runs if you run the file.
if __name__ = "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried your solutions.

```
liste_lien = tvilles['lien'].to_list()
print(liste_lien)
```

Output:

> ['https://www.ville-ideale.fr/avon_77014', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/boissettes_77038', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/boissise-la-bertrand_77039', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/boissise-le-roi_77040', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/cesson_77067', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/dammarie-les-lys_77152', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/fontainebleau_77186', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/hericy_77226', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/la-rochette_77389', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/le-mee-sur-seine_77285', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/livry-sur-seine_77255', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/melun_77288', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/pringy_77378', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/rubelles_77394', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/saint-fargeau-ponthierry_77407', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/samoreau_77442', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/vaux-le-penil_77487', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/vert-saint-denis_77495', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/vulaines-sur-seine_77533', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/barbizon_77022', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/bois-le-roi_77037', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/cely_77065', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/chailly-en-biere_77069', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/champagne-sur-seine_77079', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/chartrettes_77096', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/fleury-en-biere_77185', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/fontaine-le-port_77188', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/moret-loing-et-orvanne_77316', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/perthes_77359', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/saint-mammes_77419', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/saint-sauveur-sur-ecole_77435', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/samois-sur-seine_77441', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/thomery_77463', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/vernou-la-celle-sur-seine_77494', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/villiers-en-biere_77518', 'https://www.ville-ideale.fr/voisenon_77528']

Then I created a loop to iterate thought the list. I want to append results to my existing Google Sheet (not done yet).

```
ng_liste = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Note Générale'])
notes_theme = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Environnement','Sécurité', 'Santé', 'Sports et loisirs', 'Culture', 'Enseignement', 'Commerces', 'Qualité de vie'])

for lien in liste_lien:
  response = requests.get(lien, timeout=(5, 55))

  if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Response: ' + str(response.status_code) + '-' + str(response.reason))
  #On récupère le lien et on le transforme en texte
    header = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(lien, headers=header)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    #Global note
    ng = soup.select_one("#ng")
    if ng:
      print(ng.text)
    else:
      print("Selected element doesn't exist")
  else:
    print("Request to", lien, "failed with error", response.reason)

  # Notes
  dfs = pd.read_html(lien)
  tab = dfs[0]
```

Output:

> Response: 200-OK
> Body response:200
>
> Selected element doesn't exist
>
> File "<string>", line unknown
> XMLSyntaxError: no text parsed from document

So I have my response 200, but nothing comes... I don't know why since the result looks OK.